# How to use i18next with namespace in pure javascript function?

Tags: javascript, translation, i18next, react-i18next

I have function

```js
const myTranslation = async () => {
  const translation = await i18n.loadNamespaces(['home']);
  console.log(translation); //-> return undefinded
  console.log(translation.t('title')); //-> return Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined
};
```

How get my translation home.title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i18n.loadNamespaces` just loads the required namespaces, in order to translate you need to use `i18n.t`.

```
const myTranslation = async () => {
  await i18n.loadNamespaces(['home']);
  console.log(i18n.t('title'));
  // --------------^
};
```